# Check the current position in a Redis list of some list element

Tags: redis

I have a simple job queue on Redis where new jobs are pushed with `RPUSH` and consumed with `BLPOP`. The jobs are stringified JSON objects that have an `id` field among other things (the json string is parsed by the workers).

Each job takes some time to do, so there can be a meaningful wait time. I'd like to be able to find a job's current position in the queue, so that I can give an update to whatever is waiting on that job. That is, be able to do something like "your current position is 300... 250... 200... 100... 10... your job is now being processed".

It can be assumed that the list may grow long but never *too* long, i.e. possibly 1000 entries but not 1 million.

After looking through the docs a bit, it seems like this is maybe easier said than done. A possible naive solution seems to be to just loop through the list until the element is found. Are there any performance issues with calling `LINDEX` a couple hundred times at a time like that?

Would appreciate any suggestions on other ways this can be done (or confirmation that `LINDEX` is the only way). The whole structure (even the usage of a list, or addition of some helper map/list) can be changed if needed, only requirement is that it run on Redis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a sorted set and a counter to more elegantly solve the problem.

#### Push a job

1. Call `INCR counter` to get a counter.
2. Use the counter as score of the job, and call `ZADD jobs counter job-name`

#### Pop a job

Call `BZPOPMIN jobs` to get the first unprocessed job.

#### Get job position

Call `ZRANK jobs job-name` to get the rank of the job, e.g. the current position of the job.